# How to convert DJVU's to PDF in calibre?

Tags: pdf, epub, djvu, calibre

Im trying to use Calibre to upload some ebooks to my Kobo ebooks reader. When trying to do that, Calibre first tries to convert the file to EPUB but fails in this step. The uploaded files are EPUB files which have only the convers plus a blank page, I tried  to make it convert to PDF but the same behavior happens again, a PDF is generated with the two pages, the cover and a blank page.

I guess Calibre is trying to find text in those books Im trying to convert, but they seem not to be files with text, I guess that they're DJVU's made of scanned pages.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unzip epub file, search text in xml - change convertor. If not found text - search image files - OCR.

Comment: I use [EBookDroid](https://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/) on my Nook for reading DjVus (and PDFs).

Comment: @Geremia You can't read djvus on Kobo. I've found a hack to install android on it: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=231681

Comment: @Vÿska: Oh, does Kobo not run Android OS? If so, I wonder if there are DjVu readers for its OS.

Comment: @Geremia It actually does not have an OS. It has a very simple program made for reading PDF's and epubs.